# How to get public key from a Electrum based wallet?

Tags: electrum, bip32-hd-wallets

I have created a wallet with Electrum. Now I want to get the public key (not the address, but the public key for key-derivation).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the extended public key aka master public key then you can get that via wallet menu > information. If you mean the address specific public key go to view menu > show address, switch to addresses tab, right click on the address in question and choose details to view the public key. You can also search the addresses on that tab by pressing ctrl+f.

Comment: With a fresh wallet, the addresses tab is empty.  Does this mean you have to either send or receive BTC at least once in order to see your own public key?

Comment: @Markus it shouldn't be empty. Make sure you are using the latest version of electrum and that you see a balance in the bottom left and a green circle in the bottom right. If upgrading electrum doesn't fix it then create a thread on a [community forum](http://electrum.org/#community). Stackexchange is not suitable for a back and forth diagnoses session.